# Strings and characters in c

Tags: c, string

Is the following is right, if not then why do you think is not right?
All strings are arrays of characters but not all arrays of characters are strings?

what i would answer and is the following right: I think that all strings have last characters '\0' and program during printing out string does not see other characters after '\0', but array of characters are all characters  including the characters after '\0'

Comment: How much is this question worth on your homework?

Comment: it is not a homework.Can't i ask this question?If it is easy for you, why it is hard for you just to answer?Or if it seems so easy, it could be only a homework?

Comment: If it's phrased like homework, and shows no context or effort on your part to solve it, than duck-typing would postulate it's homework.

Comment: Sorry, may i change something in my question then? Will you answer then?

Comment: NVM, you have your answer. And the rep machine keeps churning on..

Comment: What does NVM mean?What do you mean?

Comment: @StoryTeller, you are so rude, actually, calling me as if i am asking questions that phrased from homework and if you dont like my question can't you just skip this question and go and do your work instead, don't waste time on answering "homework" questions though

Comment: A) I didn't *answer* a "homework" question. B) The site has an agenda to display high quality questions and answers to a wide array of programming problems. All users are encouraged to improve the quality of any question or answer they see, either by voting, commenting or direct editing.

Comment: I am so sorry that i am beginner in C and asking easy questions, thank you for your BIG help and support then)Good luck with high quality questions !

Comment: If it's not homework, from where did you get the question?  I'm pretty sure that you did not think it up, and put it in that manner, by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A string can be stored in an array of chars, with a extra space at the end to store the sentinel string character "'\0'" which marks the end of the string value. For example, the following two arrays both contain  characters but only the second contains a proper string representation.

array of chars (not a well formed string): [H] [E] [L] [L] [O]

array of chars with proper termination (well formed string): [H] [E] [L] [L] [O] [\0]

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, a *string* is a definition used with the standard library.  It really is not even part of the language definition unlike *array*.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.  C11 §7.1.1 1
>
> An *array type* describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the *element type*.  §6.2.5 20

*All* strings contain a null character.  An array of characters is not required to contain a null character.  With that, the answer to "All strings are arrays of characters but not all arrays of characters are strings?" should be apparent.